# An extremely simple AJAX "HTTP GET" request using jQuery 's $.ajax() method does not Work for me. Backend is a ASP.net WEB API controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to learn basics of WEB API, Im very beginner. I connected a HTML webpage to a get method in a WEB API controller in c#, using AJAX request with XMLHttpRequest object  successfully. But Im trying to figure out how to write it with jQuery $.ajax method and I just cant figure it out.

The project is solely for me figuring out how to write these requests just for fun :D, thats why it is written as trivially as possible.

What I see when I launch the HTML site is only number 7 - response from xmlhttprequest object, so the connection to the controller must work.

This is the HTML website code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
       </script>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
       let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xml.onload = () => {
           let d = JSON.parse(xml.response);
           document.write(d.Id);
       }

       xml.open("GET", "https://localhost:44335/api/employees");
       xml.send();

       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
           url: "https://localhost:44335/api/employees2",
           success: function (data) {
               document.write("gh");
           },
           error: function (data) {
               alert("chyba");
           }
       });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the backend C# WEB API Controller code

```
namespace WebApplication8.Controllers
{
    class employee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/employees")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Geti()
        {
            employee e = new employee();
            e.Id = "7";
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,e);
        }

        [Route("api/employees2")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage a()
        {
            employee v = new employee();
            v.Id = "8";
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in your browser's developer tools, both in the network tab and the console (relating to your `employees2` endpoint)?  You should at least see the call in the network tab.  If you set breakpoints in the `$.ajax` version, do any of them fire?

Comment: It seems like I spent 2 hours wondering how to write a $.ajax() functional request  just because I used an improper src to load the jQuery library in head of HTML page. Thats what I saw in the network tab. Problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix ajax on success

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
           url: "https://localhost:44335/api/employees2",
           success: function (data) {
              document.write(data.Id);
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               alert(xhr.message);
           }
       });
```